# Search possibility to display filtered data with Leaflet.VectorGrid

Tags: leaflet, filter, vector-grid, markers

I use Leaflet and Vectorgrid and I can display markers on the map.

I have a geojson file of around 42 000 markers of places in Morocco and I would like to filter it to display only markers with a series of characters

Here some lines of the geojson file : Ma.js

```
var Maroc = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "MA",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "El Abed",
        "lat": 34.47,
        "long": -1.72
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1.72, 34.47]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Oued el Aïacha",
        "lat": 35.42148,
        "long": -5.92269
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-5.92269, 35.42148]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Oued et Tleta",
        "lat": 35.49212,
        "long": -5.52349
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-5.52349, 35.49212]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Île Sainte Catherine",
        "lat": 35.90603,
        "long": -5.28704
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-5.28704, 35.90603]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Hassi Kseïr",
        "lat": 30.91992,
        "long": -3.65565
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-3.65565, 30.91992]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "lgli",
        "lat": 31.53,
        "long": -6.86
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-6.86, 31.53]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the part of javascript in Leaflet

```
var layerGroup001 = L.vectorGrid.slicer(Maroc, {
    rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,

    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
      sliced: {
        icon: new L.Icon({
          iconUrl: 'images/markers/marker-icon-2x-green.png',
          iconSize: [24, 30],
          iconAnchor: [12, 30],
        }),
      }
    },
    buffer: 512,
    maxZoom: 20,
    indexMaxZoom: 5,
    interactive: true,
  })

  .on('click', function (e) {
    var properties = e.layer.properties;
    if (properties.name > '')
      L.popup({})

      .setContent('<h3>' + properties.name + '</h3>')
      .setLatLng(e.latlng)
      .openOn(map);

  })

$.ajax(layerGroup001, function (data) {

  layerGroup001.addData(data);
});
```

Is it possible to apply a filter to search for markers with a series of characters in  `feature.properties.name` and display them on the map ?

Comment: In vector tile layer markers/icons are not individually accessible. All you can do is change style of a feature (and with this also associated icon), but for this features must have unique id , assigned by `getFeatureId` vector layer option.

Comment: Afterthought: do you want to apply filter at the time of layer creation or afterwards?

Comment: I thought I would apply the filter when I created the layer. I wonder if it would be possible to filter this file before opening with Vectorgrid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concept of vector grid layers is such that features cannot be filtered out, but just not displayed by giving them appropriate style.

You can select which features to display and which to hide in `vectorTileLayerStyles` option property `sliced`. This can be function where first parameter is feature `properties` and second parameter is zoom.

So for example in your case, if you want to display only features that contain value of `filterString` variable in feature property `name`, code could look something like this:

```
var filterString = 'Qued';

var icon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: 'images/markers/marker-icon-2x-green.png',
  iconSize: [24, 30],
  iconAnchor: [12, 30],
});

var layerGroup001 = L.vectorGrid.slicer( Maroc,{                
  rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    sliced: function (properties, zoom) {
      var style;
      if (properties.name.indexOf(filterString) >= 0)
        style = {icon: icon};
      else {
        style = {stroke: false, fill: false};
      }
      return(style);
    }
  },  
  buffer: 512,
  maxZoom: 20,
  indexMaxZoom: 5,
  interactive: true
});
```

You can later even dynamically change filter value and then use vector tile layer `.redraw()` to apply filter:

```
filterString = 'Île';
layerGroup001.redraw();
```

Comment: The code you just proposed is functional. I have just implemented it, as there are almost 42000 markers, the query takes a long time to run. I noticed that the search is case sensitive. I will modify my geojson file to replace all uppercase characters with lowercase.

Comment: If you need case insensitive search, you can use `.search` method, see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp